# Add textchange event to datagridview cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to make an autocomplete cell in datagridview c#. and I want the autocompletecustomsource dynamicly populated when the text change.

I've tried to add the textChanged event handler to the cell as suggested in
"[How to get the text from current cell in datagridview textchanged event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599154/how-to-get-the-text-from-current-cell-in-datagridview-textchanged-event)". it works. 
but some time it crashed and showing error

```
Vschost32 Error, or memory access violation.
```

any idea how to achive this?

**Update 1**

my Code

```
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
        string headerText = dgv.Columns[dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].HeaderText.ToString();
        DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb = e.Control as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;
        removeAutoComplete(tb);
        if (headerText == "Kode Barang" && tb !=null)
        {
            tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tb_kodeBarang_TextChanged);
        }
        else if(headerText == "Nama Barang" && tb!=null)
        {
            tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tb_namaBarang_TextChanged);
        }  
    }
    private void removeAutoComplete(TextBox tb)
    {
        tb.TextChanged -= tb_kodeBarang_TextChanged;
        tb.TextChanged -= tb_namaBarang_TextChanged;
        tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None;
    }
    private void tb_kodeBarang_TextChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        if (tb.Text.Length > 0 && tb.Text != "" && tb.Text != null)
        {
            tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            tb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource = getStringCollection(tb.Text,"Kode");                
        }
    }
    private void tb_namaBarang_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        if (tb.Text.Length > 0 && tb.Text != "" && tb.Text != null)
        {
            tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            tb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource = getStringCollection(tb.Text,"Nama");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the full code for getting the reference and for the TextChanged event. Are there any check about the control still being valid?

Comment: The question has been edited. how to check the control is still valid or not?

Comment: I don't like the way you treate the intiail setup: You always create a reference to tb in the showing event. Then you clear the old handles and then you set new ones. But when chaging to a different cell the new cell will have a new editcontrol. I believe you should store tb as a class level variable, check for null, clear the handles and then grab the new one and sets its handles. How reproducable are the crashes?

Comment: Thanks for the advice sir. so I'm moving tb after _if (headerText == "Kode Barang" && e.control !=null)_ . then what should I check for the null? the tb or the event handler? if it the event handler, how I know it is null or not. The crashes happen about after insert 1/2 rows or even edit different column in the same row.

Comment: The suggest edit is too long for a comment so I write it as an answer. It is untested, obviously..

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would change:

Your code:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
                           DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
    string headerText = dgv.Columns[dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].HeaderText.ToString();
    DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb = e.Control as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;
    removeAutoComplete(tb);
    ...
```

Suggested edit:

```
 DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb = null;  // keep reference

 private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
                           DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
    string headerText = dgv.Columns[dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].HeaderText.ToString();
    if (tb != null) removeAutoComplete(tb);  // check for null and unhook old tb
    tb = e.Control as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;
    ...
```

When editing a different cell/row the cell will not get the same TextBox control so you should not rely on it being the same; hence the un-hooking may fail and maybe other things as well.

Actually another check for getting the correct type of editing control is called for; after all there may be stuff like ComboBoxCells or CheckBoxCell etc..

Maybe check like this:

```
if (tb is TextBox)..
```

Comment: Thanks @TaW for te suggestion, but it still crashed.  _Exception thrown at 0x75C7D640 (shell32.dll) in MYAPP.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0031003D._

Comment: Sorry to hear that.Can you pin down the line that crashes?

Comment: on the program.cs _Application.Run(new My_Form());_

Comment: No, that is not good enough. Can you make it crash with the debugger still attached? Can you see the call stack in the VS pane? Can you describe at which action it crashes? (When entering the cell, when entering text? When pressing 'enter'? When leaving the cell?) Is there a pattern for this? Also: Can you show the code that updates the Autocompletion source? is it in `getStringCollection` ? Do you change it for each keystroke or do you detect the 'Enter' key of the CellEndEdit?

Comment: hmm any reference to attach the debugger and show the call stack ? there is no specific pattern as i know. For the string collection i change it everytime textchange on cell like textchange event on textbox.

Comment: Well the debugger is on when you run the programm from VS. There is a 'Call Stack' pane, at the bottom right in the standard layout. There you may find where the programm was before it crashed in the _shell32.dll_.. You could add breakpoints or log out  markes to find out how far the program gets. Of course finding a reproducible pattern for the crashes would greatly help..

Comment: Ha, just got the exception here too. Not sure if I have time to fix today, but I'm curious enough now to stay at it..

Comment: ha, now I know I'm not the only one.. I just thought it was my hardware failure but it apparently not. it seems textboxcell cannot handle the text event. but some of code out there said it works. just hope you got the fix. if not, i will make another way to get my goal haha,

Comment: I did a) find a god way to fix it and b) think also a way to do it your way. But I got sidetracked.. I even thought I found the reason of the crashes but that was not right.  - I'll rewrite my answer later today..

Answer (score -2):

here is the best answer example for you dear..

```
 private void dgvEntry_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
                double iTotal,iQty,iPrice;

            try
            {
                var itmColumn = dgvEntry[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
                if(itmColumn.OwningColumn.Index>0)
                {
                    iTotal = 0; iQty = 0; iPrice = 0;
                    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgvEntry.Rows)
                    {
            iQty = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dgvDOentry.Columns["itQty"].Index].Value);
          iPrice = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dgvDOentry.Columns["itRate"].Index].Value);
         row.Cells[dgvEntry.Columns["itTotal"].Index].Value = iQty * iPrice;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better accompanied with an explanation as to why your answer solves the original asker's problem so as to help future users.

Comment: Also, I'm not expert in C# but this code doesn't look properly indented - might be something else worth looking at (at the very least, the top part of your function declaration needs to be part of your code snippet).