# How to Populate other Columns

Tags: c#, .net

I'm Populating the other columns based on the given values in first column inside Datagridview.

I already Created an autocomplete textbox inside the Datagridview and now i wanted to populate the other columns which is (Price)  base on the given values in Service Name Which is link in a database, but i don't have any idea how to populate other values based on the values that i've chose .

Here is my sample Code

**AutoComplete inside the datagridview**

```
private void dgridPackage_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        string service = dgridPackage.Columns[0].HeaderText;
        if (service.Equals("Service") )
        {
            TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
            MySqlDataReader reader;
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Select Name, Price from tblservices", conn);
            AutoCompleteStringCollection DataCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            conn.Open();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {   
                    DataCollection.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
                    tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                    tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection;
                    tb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Not Found", "Report Status", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffKfM.png)

Comment: On the text change of tb populate other controls. This link might help 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876736/add-textchange-event-to-datagridview-cell

Comment: Thankyou soo much sir.. this i think i needed this one